# Is there any way to send empty optional query parameters?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I'm writing documentation for API, and got problem.

Here is link definition:

```
### Get hotels availability [GET /agent/v1/hotel/availability{?regions,hotels,from,to,limit,offset}]
```

Parameters:

```
+ Parameters 
    + regions (required,string,`399,189`)
    + hotels (optional, string, `1844`)
    + from (optional, string, `2016-03-12`)
    + to (optional, string, `2016-03-19`)
    + limit (optional, number, `1`)
    + offset (optional, number, `0`)
```

When I'm trying to send request with empty `hotels` parameter for example, apiary uses `1844` instead of empty. If I'll try to example it to empty, `hotels=hotels` is sended.

**Is there any way to send empty for optional parameter, or not send it at all?**

Here is link with screenshot:
http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1008356/09614be501945b0644fd84a06e311404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand your problem correctly. I tried to reproduce the behavior you described. I created a new API Project in Apiary and wrote following API Blueprint:

```
FORMAT: 1A

# Hotels API

# Group Hotels

## Hotels [/agent/v1/hotel/availability{?regions,hotels,from,to,limit,offset}]

+ Parameters 
    + regions (required,string,`399,189`)
    + hotels (optional, string, `1844`)
    + from (optional, string, `2016-03-12`)
    + to (optional, string, `2016-03-19`)
    + limit (optional, number, `1`)
    + offset (optional, number, `0`)

### Get hotels availability [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {"hello":"world"}
```

Then I opened console pane in the generated interactive documentation and tried to edit URL parameters:

[image: editing URL parameters]

The URL at the top is changing correctly. I made some requests with the Console and the Traffic Inspector page seems to confirm that correct parameters has been sent:

[image]

I think you'll have to refine your question and provide more information. Also, I believe this is fairly Apiary-specific topic and it may make more sense to contact Apiary Support at `support@apiary.io` instead. If e-mail isn't your thing, there's also an interactive chat:

[image]

---

*Disclaimer: At the time of writing the answer I work for Apiary.*

Comment: Thank you for response. Tried at home - http://goo.gl/4xsX2Q so it's not browser dependant. Anyway using `0` instead of value works so it's not big deal anymore.

Comment: @ineersa, this is really strange. We tried to reproduce this in Apiary on two different computers, but still unsuccessfully. Your "screencast" clearly proves it is broken for you and I'd love to know why. Would mind getting in touch on our support so we could get more details from you, please? If e-mail isn't your thing, I'm going to update my answer with instructions how to get into our interactive chat. I'd really love to get this fixed for you!